# How do I use lodash, and JS modules in general

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I just installed Node and I want to use the lodash library.  I made a new JS file in my desktop and I started the file with

```
var _ = require('lodash');
```

However, I get

```
Error: Cannot find module 'lodash'
```

How do I use the lodash library?  All I can find online says to use the import statement I already used.

Comment: You have to install any modules you want to use. Run `npm install lodash` in your command line in the folder of your project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install lodash with npm:

```
npm install lodash
```

That will install lodash into a subdirectory of your current directory called `node_modules`. Node.js knows to look there when you use `require('lodash')`.

Usually you'll have a `package.json` file that tracks your dependencies so that you can just do `npm install` to install all dependencies for a project. If you want to add lodash to `package.json` then you can use `npm install --save lodash`.

If you don't have a `package.json` for your project yet, I would recommend running `npm init` to create one.